# Django form doesnt rendering. <TestForm.forms.my_form object at 0x000002C7B3B37A20>

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to render form in my template.
It is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class StudyRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

My form:

```
from .models import *
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField


class send_request_form():
    phone = PhoneNumberField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = StudyRequest
        fields = {'name', 'phone'}
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from StudyRequest.forms import send_request_form
from StudyRequest.models import StudyRequest


def landing_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = send_request_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            R = StudyRequest(name=name, phone=phone)
            R.save()
    else:
        form = send_request_form()
    return render(request, 'NetStudy/home.html', {'form': form})
```

It is result of render:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9DQH.png)

Html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use form.as_p, form.as_table, form.as_ul, nothing helps me.

Comment: your form should inherit from django forms `class send_request_form(forms.ModelForm):`

Comment: @mahyar yep my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in forms.py Form should inherit from django forms.

```
from .models import *
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField


class send_request_form(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneNumberField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = StudyRequest
        fields = {'name', 'phone'}
```

Comment: Fields should be a list or a tuple not a dict